# SYMFONY 3 Twig conditions route

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to know how with twig display something considering the route.

```
{% if visual|default %}
                {{- wc_simple_visual(visual) -}}
            {% else %}
                <div class="preview-list-element-content-visual-default">
                  //Display the image in functions of the routn name 
                {% if app.request.get('_route') != 'live' AND f app.request.get('_route') != 'contact' %}
                    <img src="/{{ asset_version('img/live-image.jpg') }}" alt="{% if title %}{{ title }}{% endif %}" class="default-image">
            {% else %}
        <img src="/{{ asset_version('img/contact-image.jpg') }}" alt="{% if title %}{{ title }}{% endif %}" class="default-image">
                </div>
            {% endif %}
```

but like this it doesn't works, thx.

Comment: which error do you have? You should use lowercase: `and` instead of `AND`

Comment: Thx it was this i don't know why twig didn't understant uppercase

Comment: See also Twigs Documentation: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html `AND` (uppercase) is not supported, which is good.